# No database in standalone project in Unity

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, unity-game-engine

I am doing simple project with local database, my program works in editor, but when I build it to standalone project it just doesn't copy database so program doesn't work as standalone project.

But when I manually copy database to this project, it works.

Is there a way to copy this database when building?
I am using SQLite and database file is .db.

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried adding a step in the build to copy the db file?

Comment: However this is why a build isn't a distribution. F5 merely compiles the code, it's not meant to package your software.

Answer (score 0):

Every time, when you deploy your application in other environment you need create a new DB with schema and seed data to the new DB. If you need use only 1 DB for all instance of application - use remote server.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom script for building the player that also copies the file(s) for you. Here is untested code that for your help:

```
string[] scenes = { "Assets/myScene.unity" };
BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(scenes, "Build/game.unity3d", BuildTarget.StandaloneWindows, 
BuildOptions.BuildAdditionalStreamedScenes);
File.Copy(sourceFile, Path.Combine("Build", sourceFileName));//Copy your desried files
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did it by moving my database to StreamingAssets folder and now it works.